# Sqoop incremental load using Informatica BDM

Tags: sqoop, informatica, informatica-powerexchange

I am new to Informatica BDM.I have a use case in which I have to import the data incrementally (100 tables) from RDBMS into Hive on daily basis. Can someone please guide me with the best possible approach to achieve this?

Thanks,
Sumit

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop is write onces read many (WORM) approach and the incremental load is not easy stuff. There are following guideline you can follow and validate your current requirement

1. If the table is a small/mid-size and not having too many records,
   better to refresh the entire table
2. If the table is too big and incremental load has add/update/delete operation, you can think of staging the delta and perform a join operation to re-create data set.
3. For large table and large delta, you can create a version number for all the latest record and each delta may come to a new directory and a view should be created to get the latest version for further processing. This avoid heavy merge operation.

If the delete operation is not coming as change, then you also need to think how to act on it and in such case, you need to get the full refresh.

Comment: @ H Roy Thanks for replying.

But my concern was,How to handle the Incremental scenario in Informatica when we have huge number of tables.

Do I need to create dynamic mapping or some other approach I need to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic mappings for your use case where the table's name can be parameterized. This will help you to ingest the data into hive using a single mapping and the metadata of the source table will get fetched at run time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).